# Deleting rows by giving specific column names with 'dropna'

Tags: python, pandas

I have an X-dimension data set. I try to delete rows if there is any "Nan" value in the ***"lon"*** and ***"lat"*** columns

I am using the following code

```
df3 = pd.read_csv("X.csv",nrows=10)

print(df3.shape)

df3.dropna(subset=['lon','lat],how='all')

print(df3.shape)
```

The shape results (10,11) are the same but in the data set there are nan values belonging to *lat* and *lon*. I mean that I cannot delete Nan values which belong to *lat* and *lon* features.
I can't figure out where I've done wrong

Comment: could you show us the data?

Comment: When I add "inplace=True", it worked but Why does not work without this adding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dropna` returns a new dataframe without the columns unless `inplace` is specified:

```
df3 = df3.dropna(subset=['lon','lat'], how='all')
```

or

```
df3.dropna(subset=['lon','lat'], how='all', inplace=True)
```

should work.

Comment: Thank you.  After adding "inplace=True" I achieved delete it but it does the deletion process without adding it on the panda official website. Can you explain in more detail in order to better understanding

Comment: This is because often you don't want to modify the original dataframe, so you can do something like `new_df = df3.dropna(...)`. That is why the default behavior of these kinds of function is to return a modified version rather than altering the original. It also allows to do multiple operations in a single line, like `new_df = df3.dropna(...).merge(...).apply(...)`.